# Routing error in Laravel 4.1 - Controller method not found

Tags: laravel-4

I've upgraded from Laravel 4 to Laravel 4.1 in a new branch on my repo, following the steps in

`https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/upgrade.md`

The only step I wasn't able to fully follow was point 11 - add `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller` in baseController. The instruction is to replace an existing `use` statement. However in my version 4.0.9, it wasn't there.

Anyway, I am encountering a routing error when trying to hit a grouped route.

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method [audience/uk] not found.`

I could hit the route without problems in the 4.0 branch.

I believe my upgrade went ok otherwise as I could correctly see the 4.1 changes in `artisan changes'

My route looks like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function()
 {

    Route::get('upload/audience/uk',array('as' => 'get-upload-uk-audience', 'uses' => 'CSVController@getUKAudience'));

 });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The relevant log is here http://paste.laravel.com/1c73

Comment: Ahh - it's an outstanding issue - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/2850

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem using Laravel 4.1 which I solved by adding the following line right at the very top of the BaseContoller.

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```

I'm also using Codesleeve Asset Pipline and had to add the same line to the top of the AssetPipelineController to get that working too.

I did quite an extensive search on this topic and was surprised at the lack of information online.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to avoid using Route::controller.

Ref: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/2850

Thanks @Anultro from the github irc channel